# How to replace blocking code for reading bytes in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, ktor

I have `ktor` application which expects file from multipart in code like this:

```
multipart.forEachPart { part ->
  when (part) {
    is PartData.FileItem -> {
      image = part.streamProvider().readAllBytes()
    }
    else -> // irrelevant
  }
}
```

The Intellij IDEA marks `readAllBytes()` as inappropriate blocking call since ktor operates on top of coroutines. How to replace this blocking call to the appropriate one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the reputation of Ktor as a non-blocking, suspending IO framework, I was surprised that apparently for `FileItem` there is nothing else but the blocking `InputStream` API to retrieve it. Given that, your only option seems to be delegating to the IO dispatcher:

```
image = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { part.streamProvider().readBytes() }
```